# create trigger to restrict access on particular day

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

how to create trigger to restrict the insert command access from the user on particular day(eg:sunday)

Comment: When you say "restrict" do you mean "prevent", "stop"?  Or something less drastic?  And by "DML" / "access" do you mean just UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE, or do you want to restrict SELECT as well?  Please edit your question to give us more details.

Answer (score 1):

You could schedule following command sunday morning

```
ALTER DATABASE database-name SET READ_ONLY
```

and this sunday evening

```
ALTER DATABASE database-name SET READ_WRITE
```

Answer (score 1):

What an odd requirement!

If you just want to restrict access to inserts on one table, create an instead of trigger and use the day() function to determine the day of the week it is and do the insert if the day is not Sunday. Note this will be restricted to the server day not the users day if they are in a different time zone.